# Open level up window

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I clicked away my level up screen to check on some crafting recipes. Now I cannot get back to the level up window. Is there a hotkey or button for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default key for the skills window is <kbd>k</kbd>